# insert button "save to drive" on blogger

Tags: google-drive-api

I tried putting the "save to drive" blogger but I can not because my images are housed in another domain. Whenever instal obtain XHR Error button. alguen already installed on blogger who can help me.

Answer (score 0):

That is due to Javascript security restriction on origin.
Official documentation of "Save to drive" button explains some workaround for this problem.
Please check [this page](https://developers.google.com/drive/savetodrive#cors) for more information.

Comment: then if I follow the instructions, how the code would stay.
so that it can stick on blogger

Comment: someone already able to install the button "SaveTo drive" blogger.
someone who can help me to know how serious the code.